# Extracting dates from text in python

Tags: python, date, screen-scraping

This is the data  I scraped from a website.

```
[
 'Archive\nUpdated',
 'Sep 20,\n2021',
 'Data Tables',
 'Excel',
 'Sep\n03, 2019',
 'Nov 05, 2021',
 'Sep\n03, 2019',
 'Excel',
]
```

Now the thing is that I want to extract the dates, Month and years inside this list.

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried to do this?

Comment: date=[]                                                                                                                                                                      
for c in soup.find_all("div"):                                                                                                          
    date.append(c.text.strip())                                                                                                    
date

Comment: I want to scrape date and month so i scrape it with div tag beacause there is no  classname in it

Comment: You should post the code correctly formatted and in the question, below the input.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the format in which your dates appear - you can do something like this:

```
import datetime as dt

data = [
 'Archive\nUpdated',
  'Sep 20,\n2021',
   'Data Tables',
    'Excel',
     'Sep\n03, 2019',
      'Nov 05, 2021',
       'Sep\n03, 2019',
        'Excel',
        ]
data = [_.replace('\n', ' ') for _ in data]

for _ in data:
    try:
        data_date = dt.datetime.strptime(_, '%b %d, %Y')
        print(data_date.date())
    except ValueError:
        continue

#2021-09-20
#2019-09-03
#2021-11-05
#2019-09-03
```